# Ordering by the column which is connected with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have classes like this, `Drawing` has the one `CustomUser`

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict,null=True,blank=True)
    NAM = models.CharField(max_length=1024,null=True,blank=True,)

class Drawing(SafeDeleteModel):
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict,null=True, blank=True)
    update_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='update_user')
```

Now I wan to get the list of `Drawing` by sorting `Drawing.update_user.NAM`

then i made code like this,

```
class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer
    pagination_class = DrawingResultsSetPagination 
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter] 
    ordering_fields = ['id','update_user.NAM']
    ordering = ['-id']
```

then call with this url

http://localhost/api/drawings/?ordering=-update_user.NAM

http://localhost/api/drawings/?ordering=update_user.NAM

However in vain.

How can I call this ordering?

Comment: `update_user.NAM` use double underscore instead of full stop.

Comment: Thank you I can solve this with your comment and answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a double underscore to get related field so replace the dot with double underscore like this:

```
update_user__NAM
```